# Ingest zip file to Azure Data Explorer with C# SDK (Kusto.Ingest)

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

Does the ADX C# Ingestion SDK (Kusto.Ingest) support the ingestion of zip files, similar to the capability that the LightIngest tool has?
If yes, I would love to see a code snippet that demonstrates such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fully supported.

A sample project can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-samples-dotnet/tree/master/client/QueuedIngestFromStorageExample